# Angularjs: How to get value of input without ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I need to make some inputs by `ng-repeat`, and in my json file I have in object where is a property called `name`, like this:

```
"url":"find_company",
    "values":[
      {
        "name":"company name",
        "type":"input_search"
      },{
        "name":"company_phone",
        "type":"input_search"
      }
    ]
```

I want to make search in DB, in search you can find by any field or by two or more field. Field called the same as property of object. So by ng-keyup I need to send to my function

```
search(field, value)
```

two arguments. I want to do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="value in param.values">
    <input ng-if="value.type == 'input_search'" 
           ng-keyup="search(value.name, this.text)" 
           type="text">
```

How can a send to function text of this input without using `ng-model`? Where `this.text` is value of input.

Comment: Why won't you use `ngModel`?

Comment: Well I added example of how you can use `ngModel` because it's angularjs and not using `ngModel` seem wrong /unnecessary to me.

Comment: Thanks, your example helps me. The problem was that I didn't know how to use ng-model and to save the input empty, no you show me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it **with** `ngModel`:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in param.values">
    <input ng-if="value.type == 'input_search'" ng-model="value.val" ng-keyup="search(value)" type="text">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.search = function( item ) {
    console.log( item.val ); // Here you have the value using ngModel
    console.log( item.name ); // Here you have the "name" property of the element inside the loop
}
```

As you can see, you CAN use `ngModel` and by passing the object itself to the function you can access its properties from the function in the controller.

Note that there's that `this.text` in the view - I don't know what it is exactly so I dropped it from the example to make things clearer, but you can use it in your code of course.

Answer (score 4):

since you are using `ng-keyup`, you can retrieve input value with `$event.target.value`.

---

comment: `this` is fit for normal event like `onclick`, but not fit for `angular`.

refer the below example.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.showValue = function(val) {
      alert(val);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="test" ng-keyup="showValue($event.target.value)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question said **without** using `ng-model`. But I suspect you may want this because you want to customize when data-binding occurs. If that's the case, you can use `ng-model-options` with `ng-change`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="yourModel" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'keyup' }" ng-change="search()" />
```

`ng-change` fires when the model has been updated, which is after `keyup` in this case. So the value of `yourModel` will be up to date when `search()` executes.